# How to get inserted object back (with default values from database)?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm curious how I get the inserted object back. I'd like to return the constructed model object in my `create` API route in Play.

So far I have something like:

```
def create(username: String, email: String, password:String)(implicit database: Database): Option[FailureResult]  = {
  database withSession {
    implicit session => {
      val affectedRows = users += new User(username=username, email=email, password=password)
      onlyIf(affectedRows != 1){ UnexpectedErrorResult("Unexpected Error: User was not created") }
    }
}
```

The `+=` operator only returns the affected rows. Is there a way to get the object back without doing another find?

Comment: What's the point in querying for it again? You just created it and have that `User` instance in hand, right?

Comment: Why not `val user=new User(...)`? Anyways, there `returning` method of the insert operation.

Comment: the database might set some default values? such as some datetime fields or something?

Comment: Think the other question [How to return multiple values after insert?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27675813/1305344) could be of some help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slick Result To Case Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613574/slick-result-to-case-class)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `returning` method to specify some colums you want to get back from the insert. I've [seen it](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0/lifted-embedding.html#inserting) used to get back an auto-incremented id but I guess you could get all columns and reconstruct the object.

I could also point you to [my work in progress Slick/Play project](https://github.com/SlickChair/SlickChair/tree/master/app/models) where I spent quite a bit of time making these mapping look nice. By the way all of this is Slick 1.0, and lot of stuff as been improved in 2.0 such as the unified semantic of autoinc which makes the code much nicer!