# How to convert query result to case class?

Tags: slick-2.0

I'm using Slick 2.0 and I have the following `User` case class:

```scala
case class User(id: Option[Long], email: String, password: String)

class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def email = column[String]("email")
  def password = column[String]("password")

  def * = (id.?, email, password) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply _)
}
```

and I have the following function getting a user via their database id:

```
def findOneById(id: Long) = DB.withSession { implicit session =>
  val result = (for {
                  u <- users if u.id === id
                } yield (u.id, u.email, u.password)).first
  User(Option(result._1), result._2, result._3)
}
```

Is there an easier way to convert the Seq response back `result` into the `User` case class?

Comment: I briefly went over [http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/sql-to-slick.html](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/sql-to-slick.html). can you try to use `.first` (I am guessing either instead of `.run` or after it). I never used slick but it seems it should be possible to tell it to return one record

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using mapped tables? http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/schemas.html#mapped-tables

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what I have. I've added the mapped table to my question.

Comment: @benji using .first helps half way. I still get a tuple (Long, String, String), but at least it's no longer in a vector. I'm updating my question to reflect the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found my answer. I got it in part from @benji and in part from this post: [Converting scala.slick.lifted.Query to a case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234990/converting-scala-slick-lifted-query-to-a-case-class).

Instead of using a for comprehension, the following returns an Option[User], which is exactly what I need:

```
def findOneById(id: Long):Option[User] = DB.withSession { implicit session =>
  users.filter(_.id === id).firstOption
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For comprehension is easier in use with sql joins. Example:

```
def findOneById(id: Long) = DB.withSession { implicit session =>
    val query = for {
        u <- users if u.id === id
        t <- token if t.user_id = u.id && token.isActive === `A`
        } yield u    
    query.firstOption
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert the result to list of User case class, you can simply do

`result.map(User.tupled)`

However, that I will only work, if your data model is consitent. For example: Your user case class has id as optional where as it is a primary key in the DB which is wrong.

Comment: How is that wrong? The database is auto-generating the user id, and the only way I found for Slick to allow this to happen is to make the field optional and provide None when constructing and inserting new User objects.