# How to return multiple values after insert?

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

It's Slick 2.0.

I have the following:

```
mytable
  .returning(mytable.map(_.id))
  .+=(item)(session)
```

I'd like the insert not only to return the `id` but also the `name` field and the `lastname` fields. Is it possible in Slick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` determines what projection of the table is returned, so you can pick the fields you need and pack them in a tuple:

```
mytable
  .returning(mytable.map(t => (t.id, t.name, t.lastname)))
  .+=(item)(session)
```